# Notice: Undefined variable: stmt

Tags: php

i am new to php... i got some error but cannot find it please help me..
error message....

> Notice: Undefined variable: stmt.... Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on null...

```
<?php
require "conn.php";

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];


$statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM data WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss' ,$username ,$password);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($username ,$password);
$stmt->store_result();

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  

while($stmt->fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true;  
    $response["name"] = $name;
    $response["age"] = $age;
    $response["username"] = $username;
    $response["password"] = $password;
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Include your error details

Comment: You're storing the statement in `$statement`, not `$stmt`.

Comment: **Never store passwords in plain text.**. Only store password hashes generated by `password_hash()` and verify the password with `password_verify()`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Where did the variables `$age` and `$name` come from?

Answer (score 1):

Change the variable `$statement` to `$stmt`

Answer (score 0):

you make mistake in variable name used same name of variable.
**other thinks**
in **bind_result**
bind result not used this query ('SELECT * FROM ...')

if you want used bind_result use this sync

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name,age FROM data WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss' ,$username ,$password);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($name ,$age);

$response = array();  

while($stmt->fetch($stmt)){
    $response['success'] = true;  
    $response['name'] = $name;
    $response['age'] = $age;
}

echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

or used

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM data WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss' ,$username ,$password);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$response = array();  

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())){
    $response[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Thanks...the errors rectified...Thanks to all the one...